# Give R the standard (order) topology. Let U be an open subset of R. Then U can be written as a union of open intervals and rays

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Here, standard topology on Reals means its the sub-basis consisting of positive and negative open rays whose basis will give us $(-\infty, \infty)$, and $\mathbb{R}$ $\in$ $(-\infty, \infty)$. U $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ is open, which means its intersection will be closed. Now, irrationals $\mathbb{Q}$ is not part of this, therefore $\exists$ q $\in$ $\mathbb{Q}$, such that for two irrational numbers, $\exists$ a rational number r $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$, such that $(-\infty,r)$ $\cup$ $(r,\infty)$. Hence, its an union of a pairwise disjoint collection of open intervals and rays.

This is what I understood about this problem. However, it would be better if someone verifies and corrects me if I am wrong. Also, give a better notation with proper explanation and arguments. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If $U$ is open, define $x \sim y$ iff $[\min(x,y),\max(x,y)] \subseteq U$. 
This defines an equivalence relation, as is easily checked.

Its equivalence classes are the required segments and intervals.

Comment: For brevity let $[\min(x,y),\max(x,y)]=In[x,y].$  Then $In[x,y]\cup In[y,z]=[\min(x,y,z),\max(x,y,z)],$ which makes it easy to show that $\sim$ is transitive.

Comment: @daniel what's $In[x,y]$ ?

Comment: @Henno Brandsma....can u pls tell me what do u mean by equivalence classes? Here, x and y $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ , right? It says that U $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ is open that's why I asked. Also, segments and intervals, are u trying to say that segments are rays since they r not entirely intervals? Also, can we define this equivalence relation for 3 variables (i..e x,y and z) ?

Comment: We have an equivalence relation, which is always a pair-relation ($x \sim y$). The equivalence classes are all sets of the form $[x]= \{y : y \sim x\}$; all mutually equivalent points. This defines a partition of the set (so in disjoint parts). now you need to show that all classes are open and (order-convex) and connected, so must be of the form $(a,b)$ or $(a, +\infty)$ or $(-\infty,a)$(ray/segment) or $\Bbb R$ itself.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun  . I defined $In[ x,y]$ in the 1st sentence. It's the  closed interval from x to y regardless of x<y, x>y, or x=y.

Comment: ok @HennoBrandsma gotcha...thanks!! Looks like my proof is kind of similar to the idea, do u think its entirely correct or partially correct?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Ok so In means closed interval. I was confused about that coz in topology, we normally denote closed interval using $[ ]$ and open interval using $( )$. Half open intervals are $[ )$ and $( ]$. But I really appreciate your suggestions on this problem.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I proved this today, but my prof told me to show that the equivalence relations work. i.e. check n verify for reflexivity, transitivity and I guess there is another one which I have 2 show. Can u pls help me out here?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun and symmetry is the third. All three are quite clear if use Daniel’s hint. But your teacher wants to see that you actually understand the relation.